# Converting String to Bitmap (android)

Tags: android, string, bitmap, width, paint

Hi I want to convert String to Bitmap and all things are good but I don't know how to set the result Image to fit the text .
How can I do that ?
Here is my code:

```
public Bitmap textAsBitmap(String text, float textSize, float stroke,
                           int color, Typeface typeface) {

    TextPaint paint = new TextPaint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(stroke);
    paint.setTypeface(typeface);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

    float baseline = (int) (-paint.ascent() + 3f);

    StaticLayout staticLayout = new StaticLayout(text, 0, text.length(),
            paint, 435, android.text.Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f,
            1.0f, false);

    int linecount = staticLayout.getLineCount();




    int height = (int) (baseline + paint.descent() + 3) * linecount + 10;

    Bitmap image = Bitmap
            .createBitmap(****MY WIDTH***, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawARGB(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);

    staticLayout.draw(canvas);

    return image;

}
```

I even tried this but it doesn't work properly:

```
final Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);


    Bitmap image = Bitmap
            .createBitmap(bounds.width(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Instead of:

```
canvas.drawARGB(0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try this one

```
 public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArray);
    byte[] b = byteArray.toByteArray();
    String result = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return result;
}
```

Hope this will help!!!

Comment: This works, but the OP asked for the exact opposite of your answer.